# C : Checking if an item is in a list

Tags: c, arrays, list

I just learning about arrays . So I tried to write a simple exercise, in which the function should check whether  a given argument (or more)  is in a defined array.
Something like this: ./main a  -> list y

```
 int main( int argc, char* argv[] ){
 int i,n;
 char a[]={'a','5ab','na','8s'};
 for(i = 1; i < (argc); ++i){
    while (n < 4){
        if (argv[i] == a[n]){
            printf("y");
            break;
         }
    }
 }
return 0;

 }
```

Runnung this, I'm getting the warnings: "overflow in implicit constant conversion" and "multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar] "
Well, I geuss it has something to do with argv[i] == a[n]. How can I correct this?

Comment: Hm. Too many issues... Not sure where to start. OK, first - strings literals are written with double quotes.

Comment: You cannot use a char in that way, nor can you check for string equality in that way.  You are really creating a `char *a[]` and you need to look at the man page for `strcmp`

Comment: The two main problems are a misunderstanding of how strings work in C, and that `n` is never set to anything. The latter is easy to fix, you need another `for` loop, but the former... strings in C are devilishly complicated. I would suggest you work through a tutorial like [Learn C The Hard Way](http://c.learncodethehardway.org/book/).

Comment: You never initialize nor increment `n` which adds other problems.

Comment: `n` is not initialised. `n` value does not change in the loop that starts `while (n>4)` - so this can either go on forever or not at all!

Comment: You need a good (or better) C book.

Comment: Also, `==` doesn't work like you think it does. C does not have operator overloading like C++. So, `==` compares memory addresses, which may or may not be equal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C, there are two text related data types: `char` and strings. A string is a pointer to an array of chars, that by convention is terminated with a NUL character ('\0'). A `char` is a single byte representing an ASCII character.

You create a *string literal* by compiling a series of characters contained between opening and closing double quotes: `"this is a string literal"`

On the other hand, you create a `char` literal by compiling a single character expression - possibly with a *backslash escape* - between a pair of single quotes: 't', 'h', 'e', 's', 'e', ' ', 'a', 'r', 'e', ' ', 'c', 'h', 'a', 'r', ' ', 'l', 'i', 't', 'e', 'r', 'a', 'l', 's', '\n'

After the advent of code pages and multi-byte character encodings, C added (grudging) support for "wide chars" (that is, more than 8 bits used to store a single element) and for "multi-byte chars" (that is, character encodings that used 8-bit values, but required more than one to encode a single glyph).

The compiler is seeing your line initializing the array:

```
char a[]={'a','5ab','na','8s'};
```

And is assuming that '5ab' and 'na' and '8s' are an attempt, by you, to specify a wide or multi-byte character literal. It *knows* that characters (not strings) are enclosed in single quotes. It *knows* that you're using type `char`. So these can't be strings. But they aren't multi-byte characters, either.

In reality, I think you meant for them to be strings. You're probably coming from python, or bash, or perl or some other language where single quotes can delimit strings. But that's not C.

To create a list of strings, you need to know that strings are of type `char *` (or `const char *`). You then want to create an array of them - that's your list:

```
const char *list_of_str[] = {
    "hello",
    "my name",
    "is George"
};
```

You'll notice that `argv` is a list of strings. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have '5ab' in your a[] array. An array of characters can only hold single characters, such as 'a', '5', or '\n'.

Also, I'm not sure if it's a good idea to to i < (argc) in your for loop. argc is the number of elements that you pass in when your C program is ran. Try i < 4 and make sure the i in your for loop starts at 0.

Comment: There is way more wrong than that.

Comment: @David thank you. I added more suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

In an array of character each memory space is one byte that represents one character. Try using strings instead of chars.
char a[]={'a','5ab','na','8s'};

Comment: You may want to shaow an example so that he knows what to do :)

Comment: ...and cover all of the other reasons why this code is broken.

Answer (score 0):

An array is of one type only, in your case `char`.

Also your `while` loop is not correct (potentially infinite). What's `n`'s value? And where/what is the break condition?

1. You must initialize `n`'s value
2. You must ensure the termination of the loop

Comment: The while loop *could be* infinite depending on what the compiler decides to initialize `n` to, if anything.

Comment: Very likely to be infinite because `n`, being a local integer variable, is not initialized. It contains garbage.

Comment: True. but if `n` has a garbage value like `34253`, the condition is false and the loop body is never executed. If the garbage value is greater than or equal to `4`, nothing happens. It is like a game of Russian Roulette. Is the value going to be less than `4`? Either his program does nothing, or it has an infinite loop. He is going to get shot either way.